# concatenate lists as rows to make dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have few lists which have a year at their first index, followed by a name and number e.g

```
list 1 ['2017', 'Paul 2', 'Miley 4',..]

list 2 ['2016', 'Sarah 4', 'Stephanie 6'...]
```

I wish to make a dataframe (of all these lists concatenated) that has 3 columns of name, number and year

```
 name   | num   | year
 Paul      2      2017
 Miley     4      2017
 Sarah     4      2016
 Stephanie 6      2016
```

Comment: @SunAns, if one of the below solutions helped, please consider accepting one (green tick on the left), so other users know. Or, of course, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first pre-process your list data into the format[['name','num','year']...], then load them into a df. Finally concatenate the dfs.

```
list_1 = ['2017', 'Paul 2', 'Miley 4']
list_2 = ['2016', 'Sarah 4', 'Stephanie 6']

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(e+' '+list1[0]).split() for e in list1 if e!=list1[0]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(e+' '+list2[0]).split() for e in list2 if e!=list2[0]])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).set_axis(['name','num','year'], axis=1, inplace=False)

Out[78]: 
        name num  year
0       Paul   2  2017
1      Miley   4  2017
0      Sarah   4  2016
1  Stephanie   6  2016
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import izip_longest

list_1 = ['2017', 'Paul 2', 'Miley 4', 'John 5']
list_2 = ['2016', 'Sarah 4', 'Stephanie 6']

def split_names_and_numbers(input_list):
    year = input_list[0]
    return [[year] + name_and_number.split(' ') for name_and_number in input_list[1:]]

list_1_split_out = split_names_and_numbers(list_1)
list_2_split_out = split_names_and_numbers(list_2)
column_names = ['Year', 'Name', 'Number']

df_from_list_1 = pd.DataFrame(list_1_split_out, columns=column_names)
df_from_list_2 = pd.DataFrame(list_1_split_out, columns=column_names)

final_output = df_from_list_1.append(df_from_list_2, ignore_index=True)
```

`split_names_and_numbers` creates a two dimensional array representing the data for each of your dataframes. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) is the documentation for `izip_longest`. And [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is the documentation for `DataFrame.append`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a dictionary of values from your input lists and feed it into `pd.DataFrame`:

```
lst1 =  ['2017', 'Paul 2', 'Miley 4']
lst2 = ['2016', 'Sarah 4', 'Stephanie 6']

name, num = list(zip(*(x.split(' ') for x in (lst1[1:] + lst2[1:]))))
year = [lst1[0]]*(len(lst1)-1) + [lst2[0]]*(len(lst2)-1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'year': year, 'num': num})

#         name num  year
# 0       Paul   2  2017
# 1      Miley   4  2017
# 2      Sarah   4  2016
# 3  Stephanie   6  2016
```